# pytest framework (python) Usage and Invocations

Tags: python, pytest

what is the difference between all these commands / usage when i execute on the pycharm terminal or cmd

what does m ,v, k, -rxs stand for? any abbreviation to learn and understand?

1. python -m pytest
2. pytest -v
3. pytest -v -rxs
4. pytest -k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going down your list:

1. `python -m pytest` The `m` stands for `module`. This runs the pytest module within your instance of python. This is often useful if you want to run pytest with a particular version of python e.g. `python3.7 -m pytest` or `python3.5 -m pytest`.
2. `pytest -v` The `v` stands for `verbose`. This shows more information on each each test case and its specific pass or failure.
3. `pytest -v -rxs` The `v` is previously discussed. The `r` stands for short test summary info (or short test report). Each option can be used to make that report show different values `x` stands for expected fail or `xfail`. This will display the amount of xfailed tests. `s` stands for `skipped`. This will display the amount of skipped tests.
4. `pytest -k` The `k` stands for keyword. This is how you select the test case you'd like to run. It can be a portion of a test case name or a file path.

All of these usages can be found on the pytest documentation page
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html